# Baking Italian love cake

Tags: baking, parchment

Can I make 2 round love cakes in pans lined with parchment, then remove them from pans, stack and frost?  Does this change cooking time?

Comment: Can you explain what a "love cake" is and how this pan treatment differs from the standard preparation? A recipe might help, too.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you are talking about *cassata Siciliana* (Sicilian feast cake) often served at weddings.  It being thin (1 - 1.5 cm) slices of pound cake, layered with a ricotta/mascarpone cheese filling, and coated with a chocolate glaze or frosting.

In which case you can, but I recommend cutting each layer in half to make 4 total.

Comment: Cassata is made with sponge cake, not pound cake.

Comment: Sort of...made with boxed cake mix, then add ricotta, mascarpone (sinks to bottom as it bakes).  All of the instructions just have it in 9 x 13 baking pan

Comment: @joshcaswell Thank you,  I based my cassata on an old recipe I had copied years ago (preinternet).  Looking at real cassatas, they appear much better than my recipe. Having some almond paste and mixed candied fruit at hand, I know what I'm doing this weekend:)

Comment: I'm envious; hope it comes out well!